# I opened my R console and received this message - 'Error: could not find function "install.packages"'. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, console, package

This is what I see when I open the console:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Error: could not find function "install.packages"
[R.app GUI 1.73 (7892) x86_64-apple-darwin17.0]

[History restored from /Users/lakshmi/.Rapp.history]
```

The 'install.packages' function was working for me previously and I'm not sure what has changed.

Comment: You see one comment printed: `History restored from /Users/lakshmi/.Rapp.history`. The same directory may have a similar file `.RData`.  Rename it (to not delete it yet) and try again.  R will resume a session with artifacts from the previous session if you saved those.  Because this can be confusing it is generally discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Dirk. Unfortunately I deleted the .RData file, as this was one of the recommended troubleshoot steps I came across...

Is there anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems before - it may be easiest to just uninstall and reinstall R instead of figuring out the root cause.

Comment: That's fairly bad advice as it is overly broad. It is likely just the save session image from the previous use.